# C# to Extract XML Segments and Insert into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Im fairly new to C#, but I have a fair understanding of SQL

I have 1000's of XML files in a folder. I need to extract certain elements and store them in SQL.
The XMl will have Segments with Descendants that I need to store in SQL.
As an example, the below is a warehouse order 123456 which has a number of orderlines, and each orderline has a product / code segment.

I have a SQL table with 5 columns - Client, Warehouse, OrderReference, CustomerReference,Type and ProductCode.

For example

```
<UniversalShipment xmlns="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Universal/2011/11" version="1.1">
    <Shipment>
        <Order>
            <OrderNumber>123456</OrderNumber>
            <ClientReference>abcdefg</ClientReference>
            <DocketSubType>
                <Code>ORD</Code>
                <Description>ORDER</Description>
            </DocketSubType>
            <Warehouse>
                <Name>Seb's Test Warehouse</Name>
            </Warehouse>
            <OrderLineCollection Content="Complete">
                <OrderLine>
                    <Product>
                        <Code>8011</Code>
                    </Product>
                </OrderLine>
                    <OrderLine>
                        <Product>
                            <Code>8044</Code>
                        </Product>
                    </OrderLine>
                    <OrderLine>
                        <Product>
                            <Code>8043</Code>
                        </Product>
                    </OrderLine>
                    <OrderLine>
                        <Product>
                            <Code>8042</Code>
                        </Product>
                    </OrderLine>
                    <OrderLine>
                        <Product>
                            <Code>8054</Code>
                        </Product>
                    </OrderLine>
                    <OrderLine>
                        <Product>
                            <Code>8018</Code>
                        </Product>
                    </OrderLine>
                    <OrderLine>
                        <Product>
                            <Code>8061</Code>
                        </Product>
                    </OrderLine>
                </OrderLineCollection>
            </Order>
            <OrganizationAddressCollection>
                <OrganizationAddress>
                    <AddressType>SendersLocalClient</AddressType>
                    <CompanyName>The Client</CompanyName>
                </OrganizationAddress>
            </OrganizationAddressCollection>
        </Shipment>
    </UniversalShipment>
```

I have the below working but it will only post 1 line to SQL - the first Orderline, it wont loop through the orderline segment

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Load_XML_To_SQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\sebby\Desktop\MLL\XML to SQL\sample.xml");
            XNamespace ns = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
          
                Orders Order = new Orders();
                
                Order.Client = xmlDocument.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "OrganizationAddressCollection")
                                              .Elements(ns + "OrganizationAddress")
                                              .Elements(ns + "CompanyName")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                Order.Warehouse = xmlDocument.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Warehouse")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Name")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

                 Order.OrderReference = xmlDocument.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                              .Elements(ns + "OrderNumber")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                Order.CustomerReference = xmlDocument.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                              .Elements(ns + "ClientReference")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                 Order.DocketSubType = xmlDocument.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Type")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Code")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
            Order.ProductCode = xmlDocument.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                          .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                          .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                          .Elements(ns + "OrderLineCollection")
                                          .Elements(ns + "OrderLine")
                                          .Elements(ns + "Product")
                                          .Elements(ns + "Code")
                                          .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
          
                string connetionString = null;
                SqlConnection connection;
                SqlCommand command;
                string sql = null;
                SqlDataReader dataReader;
                connetionString = "Data Source=My Server;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword";
                sql = "Exec InsertXML @Client='" + Order.Client +
                                   "',@Warehouse = '" + Order.Warehouse +
                                   "',@OrderReference='" + Order.OrderReference +
                                   "',@CustomerReference='" + Order.CustomerReference +
                                   "',@DocketSubtype='" + Order.DocketSubType +
                                   "'";
                
                connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dataReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(2));
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                    command.Dispose();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    

    internal class Orders
    {
        public string Client { get; set; }
        public string Warehouse{ get; set; }
        public string OrderReference { get; set; }
        public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
        public string DocketSubType { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code so that it became safe against sql injection, added resource disposing, changed the names in accordance with generally accepted norms.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConApp5
{
    public class Program
    {
        // The connection string must be defined in a single place of the class, not in every method.
        private static string _connectionString = @"...";

        static void Main()
        {
            // Don't lump the code together, break it down into methods with talking names.
            foreach (var path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(".", "*.xml"))
            {
                Order order = ParseXml(path);
                InsertData(order);
            }
        }
        
        static Order ParseXml(string path)
        {
            XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(path);
            XNamespace ns = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var shipmentNode = xmlDocument.Element(ns + "UniversalShipment").Element(ns + "Shipment");
            // Reuse the same node.
            var orderNode = shipmentNode.Element(ns + "Order");

            Order order = new Order();

            order.Client = shipmentNode
                .Element(ns + "OrganizationAddressCollection")
                .Element(ns + "OrganizationAddress")
                .Element(ns + "CompanyName").Value;

            order.Warehouse = orderNode
                .Element(ns + "Warehouse")
                .Element(ns + "Name").Value;

            order.OrderReference = orderNode
                .Element(ns + "OrderNumber").Value;

            order.CustomerReference = orderNode
                .Element(ns + "ClientReference").Value;

            order.DocketSubType = orderNode
                .Element(ns + "DocketSubType")
                .Element(ns + "Code").Value;

            order.ProductCodes = orderNode
                .Element(ns + "OrderLineCollection")
                .Elements(ns + "OrderLine")
                .Elements(ns + "Product")
                .Elements(ns + "Code")
                .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

            return order;
        }

        static void InsertData(Order order)
        {
            // We must release resources such as the connection and the command. `using` operator do it.
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "InsertXML"; // stored procedure name

                using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    // Explicitly specify that the command calls a stored procedure.
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // The names of the sql parameters are the same as in the stored procedure.
                    // Instead of SqlDbType.NVarChar, specify the real type.

                    command.Parameters.Add("Client", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = order.Client;
                    command.Parameters.Add("Warehouse", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = order.Warehouse;
                    command.Parameters.Add("OrderReference", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = order.OrderReference;
                    command.Parameters.Add("CustomerReference", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = order.CustomerReference;
                    command.Parameters.Add("DocketSubtype", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = order.DocketSubType;

                    var parameterCode = command.Parameters.Add("Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                    foreach (var code in order.ProductCodes)
                    {
                        parameterCode.Value = code;

                        _ = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

internal class Order // singular
{
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
    public string OrderReference { get; set; }
    public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
    public string DocketSubType { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProductCodes { get; set; } // plural
}
```

Also you must change the types in the Order class, and change the types of sql parameters to those used in the database table.

Comment: Hi Alex. I've used your code and it works like a dream. I'm now stuck trying to figure out how I can use this to run through all xml files in a specific folder instead of just 1 xml. But I break your code when I do :( any recommendations ?

Comment: @SebSoum - updated. PS: Don't ask new questions in the comments. Edit your post instead. Or create a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the xmlDocument. Please try below code though I am not sure whether xe.Elements can be accessed in same manner or not.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\sebby\Desktop\MLL\XML to SQL\sample.xml");
            XNamespace ns = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            Orders Order = new Orders();


            foreach (XElement xe in xmlDocument.Nodes())
            {


                Order.Client = xe.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "OrganizationAddressCollection")
                                              .Elements(ns + "OrganizationAddress")
                                              .Elements(ns + "CompanyName")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                Order.Warehouse = xe.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Warehouse")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Name")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

                Order.OrderReference = xe.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                             .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                             .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                             .Elements(ns + "OrderNumber")
                                             .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                Order.CustomerReference = xe.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                              .Elements(ns + "ClientReference")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                Order.DocketSubType = xe.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                             .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                             .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                             .Elements(ns + "Type")
                                             .Elements(ns + "Code")
                                             .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                Order.ProductCode = xe.Elements(ns + "UniversalShipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Shipment")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Order")
                                              .Elements(ns + "OrderLineCollection")
                                              .Elements(ns + "OrderLine")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Product")
                                              .Elements(ns + "Code")
                                              .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

                string connetionString = null;
                SqlConnection connection;
                SqlCommand command;
                string sql = null;
                SqlDataReader dataReader;
                connetionString = "Data Source=My Server;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword";
                sql = "Exec InsertXML @Client='" + Order.Client +
                                   "',@Warehouse = '" + Order.Warehouse +
                                   "',@OrderReference='" + Order.OrderReference +
                                   "',@CustomerReference='" + Order.CustomerReference +
                                   "',@DocketSubtype='" + Order.DocketSubType +
                                   "'";

                connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dataReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(2));
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                    command.Dispose();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


internal class Orders
{
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
    public string OrderReference { get; set; }
    public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
    public string DocketSubType { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: hi Kazi. Thanks for your quick response. It still only adds 1 line to the table, but now its always empty values (ie. client is empty, warehouse is empty, etc). And productcode is NULL

Comment: if it helps, I added some "Consol.WriteLine(Order.Client)" after each xe, but it doesnt open in the console

Comment: Actually my answer is wrong you need to iterate only through OrderLineCollection. let me change my answer.